# Let an MVC form textarea accept HTML markup

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 ASP.NET, and I have the following Razor form.

```
<div class="editor-field description input-block-level" 
     style="min-height:100px; height:100px;">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, 
                      new { maxlength=400, @class = "span10", 
                            @style = "min-height:100px; height:100px;" , 
                            placeholder = "Description for the message" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "*")
</div>
```

How can I let the form accept HTML markup, in particular I want the form to accept hyperlinnks. e.g. 'to search in google, goto http://www.google.com' ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to switch request validation off: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Please do it for a specific property or a specific action only.